# Multi-value replace with sublime text 3

Tags: sublime-text-3

I quite often have to replace a set of text entries into multiple places into a line. I'm looking for quick ways of doing this using Sublime text 3.

An example will probably help to explain what I mean
I have a list of database names in a text file:

> ```
> Books
> Publishers
> Orders 
> Customers
> ```

And I want to convert these using the following text replacing "database name" with the values above.

```
SqlCmd -E -S Server –Q "BACKUP DATABASE [database name] TO DISK='E:\Bak\database name.bak'"
```

So I want to end up with a file containing:

```
SqlCmd -E -S Server –Q "BACKUP DATABASE [Books] TO DISK='E:\Bak\Books.bak'"
SqlCmd -E -S Server –Q "BACKUP DATABASE [Publishers] TO DISK='E:\Bak\Publishers.bak'"
SqlCmd -E -S Server –Q "BACKUP DATABASE [Orders] TO DISK='E:\Bak\Orders.bak'"
SqlCmd -E -S Server –Q "BACKUP DATABASE [Customers] TO DISK='E:\Bak\Customers.bak'"
```

There's obviously multiple ways of doing this, I'm just wondering if there are any simple ways to do this in the Sublime Text 3 editor. I'd prefer answers that don't use plugins but if there's a plugin that's suitable that would be interesting.

Comment: Probably, it is my ignorance. U tagged Sublime-text and ur title also points to sublime-text - but i see only sqlcmd - Can you clarify?

Comment: Yes, I should have made clear that this is in relation to editing a text file in sublime text. The sql stuff is just an example of what I am trying to achieve. I'll edit my question to make this clearer.

Comment: If i can provide a solution with Excel - would it be acceptable?? - because that seems to be the most easiest one

Comment: @Prasanna: Copying text (especially if it's far more complex and not just a single line) to Excel every time, using a formula, copying text back... that's easy?! You seem to be an Excel pro but it's hardly the best tool for every job.

Comment: @Karan I agree to with you. It is difficult. But we do not know the situation with this user. I was just proposing another approach toward the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very simple regex (regular expression) problem:

[image: 1]

Comment: I'll go with this as the simplest unless anyone else comes up with a better sublime specific solution. For me this soltution is simpler than @DeadEye's suggestion, which is what I normally use but is a bit fiddly and easily messed up when there is punctuation involved in the column lines.

Answer (score 1):

Use Sublime-Text column selection. So you can create a multi-cursor from the first to the last line.
Then Copy/Paste ou write your same lines. You can also use Alt or Control (depending on your OS) to move from word to word and select different lengths of words, then copy paste to create the end of the line.

TL; DR : Use Sublime-Text column selection https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/column_selection.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting it done using Sublime Text.
See the MS Excel snapshot below (you can use any spreadsheet program of ur choice).
[image]
Column A contains your data (Books,Publishers etc..)
Column B, C & D contains the static text which is not changing in all the lines.
Column E contains the formula that concatenates the strings and gives the final output.
Formula `=CONCATENATE(B1,A1,C1,A1,D1`

Comment: just realized that there is a high probability of this answer being flagged as `Not an Answer`